# Error in portfolio.spec(colnames(portfolioReturns)) : could not find function "portfolio.spec"

Tags: r

I am watching a quant finance tutorial on YouTube and ran into an error that the portfolio.spec() function can't be found. I was told it was a part of the PerformanceAnalytics package but seem to find it anywhere. Anyone know what might have happened?

Comment: I think you need to up your Google-fu.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/index.html   PortfolioAnalytics (version 1.1.0)
portfolio.spec: constructor for class portfolio

Comment: [You're not the first](https://github.com/braverock/PerformanceAnalytics/issues/143) to be confused: the function is in *PortfolioAnalytics*, not *PerformanceAnalytics*.